# H2 database change column's display name on fetch

Tags: java, h2

I have table `test` on H2 database on in java with columns `testID`,`testName` and `testAddr`. When I run this query:

```sql
SELECT testID AS 'Your ID', testName AS 'Your Name', testAddr AS 'Your Address' FROM test;
```

I get the error:

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT testID AS [*]'Your ID',testName AS 'Your Name',testAddr AS 'Your Address' FROM test;"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement [42001-214]`

How do I get alias for my column names?

Comment: In standard SQL, including H2, single quotes represent string literals, if you want a quoted identifier, you need to use double quotes, so `testID as "Your ID"`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel using double quotes did not change the alias. The column names I received are `testID, testName, testAddr`

Comment: That is because you need to check the columnLabel, not the columnName. That is a common confusion in the JDBC API, but otherwise you really have to update your question and provide a [mre]. As it stands your question is basically a typo (using `AS 'Your ID'` instead of `AS "Your ID"`)

Comment: Ah thanks. The ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel() did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MarkRotteveel I got the answer

```sql
SELECT testID as "Your ID", testName AS "Your Name", testAddr AS "Your Address" FROM test;
```

was the correct way. Further, use java's `ResultSetMetaData`'s `getColumnLabel(int i)` function to get these aliases.
These things were implicit in SQLite, but not in others.

Comment: This is pretty much a "historic" issue. The initial JDBC versions were not very clear on the distinction between columnName and columnLabel, so some drivers (like SQLite apparently) implement this incorrectly.

Comment: JDBC drivers need to read column names and aliases from database itself, but many database systems don't provide real column names of aliased columns, so their drivers have no other choice, they can only return the same name from both methods.